# Como adicionar programa ao Contextmenu do Explorer corretamente? - VB .NET

Tags: .net, visual-basic-6

Eu consegui adicionar meu programa ao contextmenu doExplorer com êxito, mas agora não consigo obter a informação sobre se o usuário iniciou o programa normalmente ou a partir do explorer.

Até achei esse code:
Dim Arguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

```
    If Arguments.Length >= 2 Then
        MsgBox('explorer')
    End If
```

Mas, como estou em Windows Forms, o construtor não é ele... Alguém saberia como fazer essa verificação?